# zu Weihnachten vs. an Weihnachten

Tags: word-usage, etymology, usage

Ich beobachte dieses Jahr, dass die deutsche Sprache plötzlich kippt, "an Weihnachten" anstatt "zu Weihnachten" zu verwenden (Radio, Zeitung, Kommentare in sozialen Netzwerken). Hat jemand dafür eine Erklärung, warum das ausgerechnet 2019 stattfindet? Oder ist das auch vielleicht nur eine Entwicklung, die hier in Mitteldeutschland stattfindet?

Comment: Mehr belastbare Daten bezüglich Deiner _Beobachtung_ bitte?

Comment: Da beide Varianten richtig und gebräuchlich sind, was ist genau die Frage? ^^ Ob der eine den anderen verdrängt?

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=an+Weihnachten%2Czu+Weihnachten&year_start=1808&year_end=2008&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Can%20Weihnachten%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Czu%20Weihnachten%3B%2Cc0

Comment: In welchem Kontext denn? Ich sehe das eine als Grund (ich schenke es dir zu Weihnachten) und das andere als Zeitangabe (an Weihnachten)

Comment: @infinitezero: Die Zeitangabe war in dieser Gegend hier auch bisher "zu Weihnachten".

Comment: @mtwde: Richtig trifft eben nicht überall zu. Es fühlt sich für mich so falsch an wie "viertel vor um".

Comment: @äüö Richtig ist beides überall. Die Frage ist eher ob und wo was gebräuchlich ist. Ähnlich wie Samstag und Sonnabend oder der/das Joghurt.

Comment: Ich finde es richtig scheiße, dass dieser Artikel geschlossen wurde. Gerade dieses Jahr ist es noch extremer geworden. "Zu Weihnachten" verwendet plötzlich keiner mehr, und es klingt so bekloppt. Es geht mir richtig auf den Senkel :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Weitgehend ist „an Weihnachten“ in Süddeutschland verbreiteter, währen „zu Weihnachten“ vor allem in Norddeutschland dominiert. Gerade in Mitteldeutschland wird also beides genutzt. Vermutlich ist es also eher eine mitteldeutsche Entwicklung.

Comment: nein, in Mitteldeutschland (= Sachsen+Thüringen+Sachsen-Anhalt) war bisher nur "zu Weihnachten" gebräuchlich. Aber Danke für die Antwort. Offenbar scheint nun der südliche Gebrauch in den Osten vorzudringen. Mir war bisher nicht bekannt, dass es zwei Varianten gab.